# Using number pipe in input gives Nan angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make all numbers to be formatted based on our application language, so I made a pipe, where I pass locale and value. (similar to number pipe, just no need to register locale in app.module) and in all edit modals where input is also  a number it has to be formatted when user clicks outside the input.
However I get error when input is formatted and user edits it again.

I added a working sample here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-pipe-comma-separator-example-arg-h3gtrw

in the input enter e.g. `11111`, then click outside you see input was formatted to `111,11` then add `.33` and it just gives NaN.

how can I fix this? I thought of removing thousand separators (and leaving just decimal separator) before returning transformed value in `my number.pipe.ts` . But how do I get thousand separator? In `EN` it's `,` in `DE` it's `.` but I didn't find function to get separator based on locale.

```js
//pipe
 */

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ 
    name: 'numberFormat'
 })
export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number | string, minFractionDigits: number = 0, maxFractionDigits: number = 2, locale: string = 'en'): string {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
            minimumFractionDigits: minFractionDigits,
            maximumFractionDigits: maxFractionDigits
        }).format(Number(value));
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="userNum | numberFormat"
                                (ngModelChange)="userNum=$event" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the docs

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

`DecimalPipe` has optional `locale` argument. Set it to correct value and it should work.

```
{{ value_expression | number [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove unnecessary literals in your pipe code:

```
value = value.toString().replace(/\D/g, "");
```

The whole code:

```
export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number | string, minFractionDigits: number = 0, 
        maxFractionDigits: number = 2, locale: string = 'en'): string 
    {
        value = value.toString().replace(/\D/g, "");
        console.log(`value:`, value)        
        return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
            minimumFractionDigits: minFractionDigits,
            maximumFractionDigits: maxFractionDigits
        }).format(Number(value));
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to make 11,111,55:

```
value = value.toString().replace(',', "");
```

[A stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-pipe-comma-separator-example-arg-yumhfd?file=app/shared/number.pipe.ts)

UPDATE 1:

You can make decision based on locale:

```
if(locale =='en')
   value = value.toString().replace(/\D/g, "");
else
   value = value.toString().replace(',', "");
```

Or try to use built-in [Angular decimal pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#description). It has parameter `locale`, so your unnecessary code such as `if` or `else`can be eluded.

Comment: If I set minFractionDigits=2 and then add numbers after decimal separator they are just added to the whole number e.g.  I have number 11,111.00  and want to make 11,111,55 and it becomes  1,111,155.00

Comment: I'm sorry... I made a typo there I meant 11,111.55 :( and yes, `value.toString().replace(',', "");` this would work if locale is `EN` but in german language number looks like 11.111.111,15 so it that case it should remove `.` and not `,`. And I'm not sure how to get thousand separator in different languages

Answer (score 0):

just initialize it with default value 0 or you can  use mask directive (ngx-currency)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for is described here: https://angular.io/api/common/NumberSymbol

So like this:

```
getLocaleNumberSymbol('de-DE', NumberSymbol.Decimal);
```

Please also note that you have to register your locale in your module:
https://angular.io/api/common/registerLocaleData

```
registerLocaleData(localeDe, LOCALE_ID, localeDeExtra);
```

I made a small demo for the usage: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-locale-number-symbol